# BufferedReader Timeout

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I am reading values from a module via BufferedReader.readline(). After the values are being requested by HTTP Get Method, the sendAndReceive function is executed. This function is working many times (approx. 100 GET Requests). After that successful requests I get SocketTimeoutExceptions from read timeout. Its exactly hanging at the line = reader.readline() position and then throws the Read TimeOut Exception

```
private synchronized String sendAndReceive(String s) {

    try {

        out.write(encrypt(s));
        out.flush();

        String line = "";
        String read = "";

        for (line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                read += line;
                if (reader.ready() == false && !read.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return read;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception Send and received: {}", e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried different versions of making the for loop a while loop, closing the reader but none of these methods work. The reader and socket are defined in another function and are executed at the beginning of the program.

```
socket = new Socket("myip", "myport");

socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

out = new DataOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream()
);

reader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()
         )
);
```

Maybe someone can help me out with my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you verified whether the process at the other end of your socket connection is actually writing to the socket so there is content available to read?

Comment: When I open the Endpoint then I receive no values when there is readtimeout. I receive an empty list of values. When its on the other hand successful, i receive my values from my list. Thank you Ralf for your comment.

Comment: What do you mean with "open the Endpoint"?

Comment: When I make a GET Request e.g in firefox (open the link), then it displays there the json with valid data from my module. If the Read timeout occurs, there is no json data displayed.

Comment: You are talking http protocol via plain socket? Don't. Use the JDK HTTP Client if you are on JDK 9 or above or a 3rd party library like [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you. What is the advantage of using these ones over the plain socket? I think that the problem is more in the module readout. The module consists of sensors that give information like the velocity. And at some point the Bufferereader from this module throws the ReadTimeOut.

Comment: Simply look at the code base of the Apache http client: It is definitely non-trivial. That's what you are getting yourself into if you try to use plain sockets.